# incremental integer with flag (or other) package in go?

Tags: go, command-line

Some unix tools allow to set the verbosity level by giving the `-v` commandline switch several times. So `-v` would be 1, `-vv` or `-v -v` would be 2. Perl, where I come from, has this in `Getopt::Long` like this: `GetOptions ('verbose+' => \$verbose);`.

As a go newbie, I couldn't yet figure out how to achieve this. The only option I found yet is, to use `-v` with an integer value so `-v 2`.

**Update**: I've now decided to use a non-standard library as it seems very convenient to use. https://cli.urfave.org/v2/getting-started/

Comment: You may register `-v`, `-vv` and `-vvv` bool flags, which when provided, you set the log level to `1`, `2` or `3` accordingly.

Comment: Nice idea. If nothing else comes around, I might consider it. But I already found the promising looking https://cli.urfave.org/v2/getting-started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go `flag` package does not use [GNU-style options](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Styles.html), so it does not differentiate between short and long options with the ability to combine short options. If you want to use `-v`, `-vv`, `-vvv` you will need to specify independent flags for these (which a lot of programs actually do), or use a non-standard flag package.

You can make a flag value which increments with multiple invocations by implementing the [`flag.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Value) interface. By also implementing `IsBoolFlag` you can further instruct the parser to not include the following argument as the flag value to set, and makes `-v` equivalent to `-v=true`.

```
type incrementor int

func (i incrementor) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(i))
}

func (incrementor) IsBoolFlag() bool {
    return true
}

func (i *incrementor) Set(string) error {
    (*i)++
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2HPfVng-a8J